# Problems with connecting Outlook 2010 to Exchange account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, exchange

I tried to find a similar question already answered but I haven't succeeded, so sorry if an answer is already there.

I am employed for company A, but usually work at company B's premises. My corporate e-mail is hosted by company A. These two companies have of course different Windows domains.

Recently I tried to configure my Exchange e-mail account in Outlook 2010 on company B's computer, but I couldn't get it to work. The problem appears when I need to provide login credentials for my mail account. I enter domainA\username and password, but after a while Outlook spits out a message that "name could not be found" (or similar).

Out of curiosity I tried to do the same on my home computer, using exactly the same login/pass, and it worked straight out of the box! Seems that the Exchange Server is correctly published to the outside world. So I am completely lost here.

I also tried Microsoft Connectivity Analyzer - it was successful in connecting to my account from companyB's machine. Then I decided to take a peek on network traffic that takes place when I enter login credentials into Outlook's prompt box and press Enter. This is where I see some strange behavior: Outlook exchanges a couple of messages with the server, then it sends TCP RST messages to it (That's right! The client seems to be terminating the connection...).

So my question is: has anyone seen a similar behavior and has a clue of what might be happening here? Or maybe a tip on how to investigate this further? Is it possible that some Windows policy settings in company B's are preventing me from configuring my e-mail from another company in such brutal manner?

The only difference between company B's machine and my home computer e-mail account settings I have found is a checkbox labeled "Encrypt connection between Outlook and Exchange Server". On company B's machine it is unchecked and disabled so that I can't change it, but it is checked and enabled on my home computer.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem. It was actually the "Encrypt connection between Outlook and Exchange Server" option. Unfortunately, error messages Outlook is producing are totally from outer space.